# C++ promises and Futures giving errors

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am new to using C++ multithreading features, what i am trying to do here is to create a bot that makes a move in a given time. So I tried creating threads, each calculating one depth more than the previous one, and uptil which ever thread the execution completes, after the given time, I allocate the result value to it.

```
void findValue(promise<vector<pair<int,int>>> &pr, vector<vector<int>> &board, int depth, int player){
    vector<pair<int,int>> result = minimax(board, depth, player, -10000, 10000);
    pr.set_value(result);
}

void debugBoard(){
    int maxDepth = 5;
    auto  board = customPosition();
    int turn = 1;
    int startTime = clock();

    vector<pair<int,int>> result;
    vector<thread> threads;
    vector<future<vector<pair<int,int>>>> futures;

    for(int i=1;i<=maxDepth;i++){
        promise<vector<pair<int,int>>> prms;
        futures.push_back(prms.get_future());
        auto nBoard = board;
        threads.push_back(thread(&findValue, ref(prms),ref(nBoard), i, turn));
    }

    this_thread :: sleep_for (chrono :: seconds(5));

    int finalDepth = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<maxDepth;i++){
        if(futures[i].wait_for(chrono :: seconds(0))==future_status :: ready) result = futures[i].get(), finalDepth =i+1;
    }

    cout<<endl<<"Result calculated up till "<<finalDepth<<" depth, and is\n";
    printInfo(result, startTime);

    for(int i=0;i<maxDepth;i++){
        threads[i].join();
    }
    
    board[result[1].first][result[1].second]=board[result[0].first][result[0].second];
    board[result[0].first][result[0].second]=0;
    printBoard(board);
}
```

Please Help!! the compiler throws the error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
terminate called recursively
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I am expecting to know what is wrong in my code. I tried using vector of promises and futures, since im new to use multithreading features, not just in cpp, but any other language as well.

Comment: I would think creating `prms` locally in a loop would cause it to be destroyed before the thread finishes and cause issues at least

Comment: I came across this type of code at another post, here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062091/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-vector-of-promises-and-collect-in-a-vector-of

Comment: That one uses `move` to keep the promise alive, it’s a big difference

Comment: I used that same code, used the move semantics and lambda function, now i got the error "terminate called recursively"

Comment: You give the thread references to local variables `prms` and `nBoard`. By the time the thread actually runs and tries to use those references, the variables are already destroyed, and the references are dangling. Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: should i try creating vector of promises, i read somewhere that its not good and raises exceptions